# can't insert into sqlite database, error: Table doen't exist

Tags: java, android, sqlite, android-studio

I have been trying to solve what seems like a simple problem for the last 3 days, I am trying to insert a record into an sqlite database from an activity, I have searched for the issue without look. Below you find my activity code and DBHelper code. dbhelper CODE:

```
  public Long insertResult(String QUEST_ID,String test1,String test2) {
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    ContentValues initialValues = new ContentValues();
    initialValues.put("Question", QUEST_ID);
    initialValues.put("Rights", test1);
    initialValues.put("Wrongs", test2);
    Log.d("Result:", "Rights " + initialValues.get("Rights"));
    return  db.insertOrThrow("Results", null, initialValues);
}

from the mainactivity
 long ins = myDbHelper.insertResult("test","test2","test3");
```

Comment: Show DBHelper calss fully if possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Results table doesn't exist in the database.

It looks like your `DBHelper` is extending `SQLiteOpenHelper`. You should override the `onCreate` method in `DBHelper`. For example, add something like this:

```
@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    db.execSQL("create table Results (_id integer primary key autoincrement, Question text not null, Rights text not null, Wrongs text not null);");
}
```

If you ever change your database schema you'll also need to override the `onUpgrade` method.

Comment: Try uninstalling the application if this doesn't have an effect.

Comment: Even if completely uninstalled the app from the emulator?

Comment: @user998548 I'm not sure what you mean. Android drops an application database when the application is uninstalled. The `onCreate` method is run when the database is created. Therefore, reinstalling the application forces the database to be created and the `onCreate` method to be run.

Comment: I was uninstalling the app, and still after I created the table in sqlite browser, reinstalled the app, I was getting the error, "table doesn;'t exist'